# How do you use a named function with event ui in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
$( ".timebox" ).draggable({    
     containment: "parent",
     axis: "x" ,
     drag: refactorTimebox(event, ui)
});
```

and I want to call the function `refactorTimebox(event, ui)`. How do I pass the `event` and `ui` variable to my function.

The line drag: `refactorTimebox(event, ui)` doesn't work.

This is the refactorTimebox function:

```
function refactorTimebox(event, ui){
     console.log(ui.position);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".timebox" ).draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    axis: "x" ,
    drag: refactorTimebox
});
```

You only need to pass a reference to a function, not call it.

Answer (score 1):

Just write the function name without method signature.

```
$( ".timebox" ).draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    axis: "x" ,
    drag: refactorTimebox
});
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cb8rZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it by name

```
$( ".timebox" ).draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    axis: "x" ,
    drag: refactorTimebox
});
```

The plugin will call it with the parameters